# What Are The Best Practices For String Data Field Sizes?

Tags: sql-server, database, database-design, data-structures

Are there any recomended field sizes for commonly used string data storage types? For example things like FirstName, LastName, AddressLine1, AddressLine2, City, State, PostalCode, EmailAddress etc. I am sure anyone who has created a table to store these commonly used data fields has had to make a decision as to what maximum size to use.

What did you base you value on?

Do you have some kind of formula that you use to make the decision(such as all fields sizes are a multiple of 8)?

Does your company have a guideline so all tables that contain these fields are uniform?

Is this just a personal thing?

I know for me if I had a set standard, I wouldn't have to stop and think about it and end up with fields of different sizes. This uniformity would also be great when working on the UI as it would be easier to set the maxlength on input fields and any data validation code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Keep in mind that the US Postal Service only allows for lines of 40 characters. Thus, 173438 Martin Luther King Memorial Parkway SE, Suite 1124 would be converted by a CASS application into something like:

```
173438 Martin Luther King Pkwy SE
Suite 1124
```

For addresses, I would start with the USPS guidelines and then if you plan on supporting international clients, look at those country's postal standards. If the address is never going to be queried, filter, sorted or used on an actual letter, then you might as well make a single column typed as nvarchar(max) (BTW, this never ends up being the case and thus I always end up needed separate columns for city, state, postal code etc).

Of late, I have gotten out of the habit of using individual columns for the lines of a street address. Instead, I use a single nvarchar(max) and split on line break (\r\n or just \n). In this way, I don't have to add a new column when one user wants a five line address excluding the city, state and postal code.

I typically use nvarchar(25) for names. I've yet to run across an individual with one part of their name that was longer than 25 characters. I'm not saying it isn't possible, I've just never seen it in a live environment.

Comment: +1 Good point about field sizes and using the data for mail pieces. The UPS shipping system we use here has a max length of 35 characters for address lines.

Comment: Indian names can be very long :) I have definitely seen single name parts longer than 25 chars especially when hyphenated.... random eg Abhimithra-Karthikeya (only 21 chars I know but you get the picture)

Comment: @Grantly - I think there may be passport restrictions on the length of a person's surname. I agree that breaking up people's names into first, last etc. is a very US/Western European attitude and for names. If two fields were used (e.g. first and surname), where _each_ is 25 char, then you actually have 50 char for a person's name overall. Still, if a person's combined name were 50 chars, the postal service will either ignore it or cut it off in when electronically processed.

Comment: @Thomas The US passport allows 35 chars (each) for all 3 name parts, but that is the US :)  I think the Surname is never truncated for passports.  Similarly, electronic processing has to cope with edge cases and allows a greater size than actually specified.  Imagine Hawaiian, Nepalese names etc - Royal titles, these things get rather long...